# Python Spark Cumulative Sum by Group Using DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I compute the cumulative sum per group specifically using the `DataFrame` `abstraction`; and in `PySpark`?

With an example dataset as follows:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( [(1,2,"a"),(3,2,"a"),(1,3,"b"),(2,2,"a"),(2,3,"b")], 
                                 ["time", "value", "class"] )

+----+-----+-----+
|time|value|class|
+----+-----+-----+
|   1|    2|    a|
|   3|    2|    a|
|   1|    3|    b|
|   2|    2|    a|
|   2|    3|    b|
+----+-----+-----+
```

I would like to add a cumulative sum column of `value` for each `class` grouping over the (ordered) `time` variable.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of a window function and the Window.unboundedPreceding value in the window's range as follows:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowval = (Window.partitionBy('class').orderBy('time')
             .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df_w_cumsum = df.withColumn('cum_sum', F.sum('value').over(windowval))
df_w_cumsum.show()
```

```
+----+-----+-----+-------+
|time|value|class|cum_sum|
+----+-----+-----+-------+
|   1|    3|    b|      3|
|   2|    3|    b|      6|
|   1|    2|    a|      2|
|   2|    2|    a|      4|
|   3|    2|    a|      6|
+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. "rowsBetween" is the correct one to use instead of "rangeBetween". The cum sum will be incorrect if the "orderBy" column has duplicated values in each partition.

Comment: @Tim thanks, that saved my life! Was confused why it didn't work anymore (it worked before), changing it to rowsBetween solved the issues.

Answer (score 18):

To make an update from previous answers. The correct and precise way to do is :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowval = (Window.partitionBy('class').orderBy('time')
             .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df_w_cumsum = df.withColumn('cum_sum', F.sum('value').over(windowval))
df_w_cumsum.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried this way and it worked for me.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

from pyspark.sql import functions as f

import sys

cum_sum = DF.withColumn('cumsum', f.sum('value').over(Window.partitionBy('class').orderBy('time').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))
cum_sum.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I create this function in this link for my use:
[kolang/column_functions/cumulative_sum](https://github.com/MahdiHGZ/kolang/blob/5e3fc81e64eab8c9e15e16fc8bface7ff2a04e57/kolang/column_functions.py#L186)

```py
def cumulative_sum(col: Union[Column, str],
                   on_col: Union[Column, str],
                   ascending: bool = True,
                   partition_by: Union[Column, str, List[Union[Column, str]]] = None) -> Column:
    on_col = on_col if ascending else F.desc(on_col)
    if partition_by is None:
        w = Window.orderBy(on_col).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    else:
        w = Window.partitionBy(partition_by).orderBy(on_col).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    return F.sum(col).over(w)
```