# PySpark DataFrame: Find closest value and slice the DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I've done enough research and haven't found a post that addresses what I want to do.

I have a PySpark DataFrame `my_df` which is **`sorted`** by `value` column-

```
+----+-----+                                                                    
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   A|   30|
|   B|   25|
|   C|   20|
|   D|   18|
|   E|   18|
|   F|   15|
|   G|   10|
+----+-----+
```

The summation of all the counts in `value` column is equal to `136`. I want to get all the rows whose `combined values >= x% of 136`. In this example, let's say `x=80`. Then `target sum = 0.8*136 = 108.8`. Hence, the new DataFrame will consist of all the rows that have a `combined value >= 108.8`.

In our example, this would come down to row `D` (since combined values upto D = `30+25+20+18 = 93`).

**However, the hard part is that I also want to include the immediately following rows with duplicate values. In this case, I also want to include row `E` since it has the same value as row `D` i.e. `18`.**

I want to slice `my_df` by giving a percentage `x` variable, for example **`80`** as discussed above. The new DataFrame should consist of the following rows-

```
+----+-----+                                                                    
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   A|   30|
|   B|   25|
|   C|   20|
|   D|   18|
|   E|   18|
+----+-----+
```

One thing I could do here is iterate through the DataFrame `(which is ~360k rows)`, but I guess that defeats the purpose of Spark.

Is there a concise function for what I want here?

Comment: added a better description

Comment: Can you share the code that yo use to `sort` the DataFrame? Is it based on the `value`? Or `value` and `name`?

Comment: It's sorted by `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are quite strict, so it's difficult to formulate an efficient solution to your problem. Nevertheless, here is one approach:

First calculate the cumulative sum and the total sum for the `value` column and filter the DataFrame using the percentage of target condition you specified. Let's call this result `df_filtered`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.orderBy(f.col("value").desc(), "name").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
target = 0.8

df_filtered = df.withColumn("cum_sum", f.sum("value").over(w))\
    .withColumn("total_sum", f.sum("value").over(Window.partitionBy()))\
    .where(f.col("cum_sum") <= f.col("total_sum")*target)

df_filtered.show()
#+----+-----+-------+---------+
#|name|value|cum_sum|total_sum|
#+----+-----+-------+---------+
#|   A|   30|     30|      136|
#|   B|   25|     55|      136|
#|   C|   20|     75|      136|
#|   D|   18|     93|      136|
#+----+-----+-------+---------+
```

Then join this filtered DataFrame back on the original on the `value` column. Since your DataFrame is already sorted by `value`, the final output will contain the rows you want.

```python
df.alias("r")\
    .join(
    df_filtered.alias('l'),
    on="value"
).select("r.name", "r.value").sort(f.col("value").desc(), "name").show()
#+----+-----+
#|name|value|
#+----+-----+
#|   A|   30|
#|   B|   25|
#|   C|   20|
#|   D|   18|
#|   E|   18|
#+----+-----+
```

---

The `total_sum` and `cum_sum` columns are [calculated using a `Window` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946349/python-spark-cumulative-sum-by-group-using-dataframe).

The Window `w` orders on the `value` column descending, followed by the `name` column. The `name` column is used to break ties- without it, both rows `C` and `D` would have the same cumulative sum of `111 = 75+18+18` and you'd incorrectly lose both of them in the filter.

```python
w = Window\                                     # Define Window
    .orderBy(                                   # This will define ordering
        f.col("value").desc(),                  # First sort by value descending
        "name"                                  # Sort on name second
    )\
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0) # Extend back to beginning of window
```

The `rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)` specifies that the Window should include all rows before the current row (defined by the `orderBy`). This is what makes it a cumulative sum.

Comment: imagine there is a row with `X 18` .. the `join` would also produce that row in the output.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala but OP said that the DataFrame is sorted by value descending (and anyway the Window function handles that).

Comment: even when it is sorted, it doesn't matter right..`join` just gets all rows with that value.

Comment: that's correct, but the way the question is formulated implies that all rows with the 18 need to be included. (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: *following* implies a sort order. Since the DataFrame is sorted by value, the rows with the same value will **always** be immediately following. None of the higher values would appear elsewhere in the DataFrame.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala By immediately following, I did not mean just 1 row - it could be multiple rows with the same value. Since it's sorted bye `value`, they're bound to be next to each other.

Comment: @pault is right, that's what I wanted and this solution does exactly that. Although, it'd be great if you could explain what `w = Window.orderBy(f.col("value").desc(), "name").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)` means. I'm new to this function. The `df` is already sorted by `value`, why are we ordering them again?

Comment: right..i was under the assumption the df was ordered by name..in which case something like `(E,18) (F,19),(G,18) (H 20)` returns incorrect results with `join`..because `(G 18)` would be returned too.

Comment: @kev I added an explanation of the Window with a link to a post that shows how to do a cumulative sum in pyspark. The DataFrame is *not* ordered- DataFrames are inherently unordered unless you explicitly specify an ordering.

Comment: @pault Thanks a lot. One question though, since the `df` is already sorted by `value`, why are we ordering by `value` in `desc` again in the `Window` function?

Comment: @kev do not think about Spark DataFrames as having any order. Even if it looks sorted, it's not guaranteed to be so under the hood. Spark distributes the data over multiple machines, which allows operations on them to occur in parallel. Since each executor does not have to worry about order, it can work on its part of the data independently. When you need an order, you have to specify *how* to sort and Spark will then shuffle the data between executors as needed. So the statement *`df` is already sorted by value* is false.

Comment: @kev as a side note, shuffling is one of the most expensive steps in a spark job. You should try to avoid shuffles if possible- this is why I said it's hard to formulate an efficient solution to fit your requirements.

Comment: @pault yeah you're right. if your solution takes too much time, I might remove the constraint of including all rows with same values in `value` column.

Answer (score 3):

Use pyspark SQL functions to do this concisely.

```
result = my_df.filter(my_df.value > target).select(my_df.name,my_df.value)
result.show()
```

Edit: Based on OP's question edit - Compute running sum and get rows until the target value is reached. Note that this will result in rows upto D, not E..which seems like a strange requirement.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# Total sum of all `values`
target = (my_df.agg(sum("value")).collect())[0][0]

w = Window.orderBy(my_df.name) #Ideally this should be a column that specifies ordering among rows
running_sum_df = my_df.withColumn('rsum',f.sum(my_df.value).over(w))
running_sum_df.filter(running_sum_df.rsum <= 0.8*target)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I need to do some other operations as well, please check the update

Comment: unfair to change the question entirely after it has been answered.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for answering though. I still need to figure out a solution which takes care of the duplicate values.