# How to rank the column based on each occurrence in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have pyspark dataframe with 3 fields as shown below (Unique Idn, visit time, new visit), I want to create another new fields (visit seq - yellow highlighted) based on every time new visit happens (as 1) for each unique idn.

[image]

So every time there is new visit for each unique identifier, it should increment the counter. Its kind of visit number. Example for Unique Idn, 11, visit start at 1/11 6:24 and ends at 1/11 6:26 and its tagged as visit 2 starting from 1/11 6:24 till 1/11 6:26.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Spark Cumulative Sum by Group Using DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946349/python-spark-cumulative-sum-by-group-using-dataframe)

Comment: To expand on that a little: It seems like you want to partition by `unique idn`, then order by `visit time`, then take a cumulative sum of `new visit`.

Comment: So every time there is new visit per unique identifier, it should increment the counter. so its kinds of visit number. example for Unique Idn, 11, visit start at 1/11 6:24 and ends at 1/11 6:26 and its tagged as visit 2 starting from  1/11 6:24 till  1/11 6:26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranking in PySpark can be achieved by using the Windows Function. For obtaining sequence number, the `row_number` function can be used.

**Snippet:**

```
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window_spec = W.partitionBy(["unique idn"]).orderBy(F.col("visit time").asc()).rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df_visit_seq = df.withColumn("visit_seq",F.sum(F.col("new visit")).over(window_spec))
```

Comment: No this did not work, it creates the sequence like row number.

Comment: I have edited the solution. Can you chk with the new one